# ImageView padding above and below image

Tags: java, android, image, imageview

I am trying to set the image of an ImageView from a byte array like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

But the image appears to have some quite large black padding at the top and the bottom, even though the actual image data does not have these. The ImageView is at the top of a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView, any ideas?

My ImageView is designed like this:

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/imageView"/>
```

Comment: Wierd. Have you tested if the same happens with a bitmap from the resources ? Does that also show the borders ? Also you could try playing with android:scaleType in the imageView definition. Might help.

Comment: After adding `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`, it's been fixed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved, I added

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Into the XML file.